# Bootstrap rendering inconsistency

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, twitter-bootstrap

I have a rendering inconsistency between Chrome (correct) and Firefox (incorrect) when using Bootstrap. This is my code (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zzxRC/)):

```
<div class='container'>
    <form class='form-horizontal well span6 offset3'>
        <label class='control-label'>Testy</label>
        <div class='controls'>
            <select></select>
        </div>
    </form>
    <legend>Hello!</legend>
</div>
```

What is the cause of the inconsistency? How can I fix the Firefox rendering so that it matches Chrome's?

Comment: Do you use <!DOCTYPE html> ?

Comment: @NitzanShaked: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be the way that Firefox and Chrome render the `fieldset` tag, at least with the non-responsive version of Bootstrap you're referencing.  In an effort to eliminate variables, I removed the reference to Bootstrap and linked to [bootstrapcdn.com's version](http://bootstrapcdn.com), which seemes to fix the problem.

If nothing else, you could always add a bit of CSS to the `fieldset` tag to ensure it renders the same across all modern browsers.

<strike>fieldset { clear: both; }</strike>

**Update:** Looks like I was not paying attention, I've updated this answer to reflect CSS on the `legend` tag, rather than `fieldset`.  [JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/NGewr/).

`legend { clear: both; }`

Comment: I've updated my answer with a supporting fiddle and the _correct_ CSS selector.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The legend tag should be placed within the form tag and it should also have a fieldset tag placed around it.

See this example from Bootstrap:

```
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>Legend</legend>
<label>Label name</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type something…">
<span class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</span>
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox"> Check me out
</label>
<button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

And for your code it would be:

```
<div class='container'>
 <form class='form-horizontal well span6 offset3'>
  <fieldset>
   <label class='control-label'>Testy</label>
   <div class='controls'>
    <select></select>
   </div>
   <legend>Hello!</legend>
  </fieldset>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: A legend can only be used as a child of a fieldset element which in turn is a child of a form tag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/legend

Comment: [What he siad](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/legend.html). In fact, technically, only as the child of a `fieldset` tag, as @BillyMoat notes in his answer.

Comment: Ok, got it: http://jsfiddle.net/zzxRC/4/. Please see my answer. @BillyMoat: That's not what I want!

Comment: To make it valid HTML you'd still need a fieldset around it. I suspect you don't really need a legend tag for what you want here. Might be better to just use a custom styled h2 or div.